# How to avoid running single application 2 times in dual core processor

Tags: android, multithreading, shell, adb

I created small application with threading, when I run this application in single core its working perfectly.

Same application in multi-core (dual core) running twice with different PID numbers. With and without for loop the result is same.

Please help how to avoid running application two times.
Here is piece of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < System.Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
{
    Thread thCurrent = new Thread(sampleMethod);                        
     thCurrent.Start();
     thSubThreads.Add(thCurrent);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Need to avoid runing same application twice in 2 core processor device(galaxy s3).First time it run with no problem, if i run second time it get stuck(ie same application running  2 times with different PID checked with PS command)

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? What exactly goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the two threads you start when your main activity starts, but the threads are left running also when the program suspends, and the two more threads are inadvertently launched every time the program resumes from the background.

Android calls the [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method also if the application just restarts from the frozen state. You need to get a way to know if your two backgrounds threads are already running and do not start them second time if so.

One of the possible ways to track these launched processes is to assign the created threads to the static fields in the main activity. On create, you should be able to check if the thread fields are not null and the threads are alive.

onCreate takes a parameter (bundle) where you could look for the stored state. However your two threads probably would not be stopped if the application has been truly suspended and classes unloaded (unless maybe it cannot in such case?). Hence I am not sure if it is good to store booleans like "the threads have been launched" in this bundle and later rely on them.

Even better would be to stop these threads on onStop() and start them on onStart().

Comment: Doesn't Android call OnResume, not OnCreate, when continued from background?

Comment: I do observe some calls of OnCreate, also obtaining my saved state as parameter. Maybe this depends on lifecycle configuration in the manifest.